# Updating the composer.phar on Symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have an already started Symfony2 project. I need to install a [new bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle), and as I saw i need to add a new line to my composer.json and then execute the update command.

The thing is, my composer.phar file and the .json are on different folders.

```
/httpdocs/composer.json
/bin/composer.phar
```

So after I add this line to the .json file:

```
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
```

If then i try `/bin/php composer.phar update doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` i got an error saying that the composer.json is not there and is correct of course. So my doubt is WHY thoose files are in different folders? does the previous developer make a mistake? Should I move the files to a same folder? To `bin` or `httpdocs`?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter where the `composer.phar` lives. The relevant part, that your **current working directory** is in the symfony project (where the `composer.json` lives). Then simple execute composer (if the execute bit is set, no call to php is required).

```
/bin/composer.phar update doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a *global* composer.phar and use only this one. This is how you would normally have it on a development machine where you have multiple composer projects.

Some people tend to put a composer.phar into their projects so they can deploy it together with their application.

**Solution to composer complaining about the missing composer.json:**

you have to change your **working directory** to the path where the *composer.json* you want to use is located. ( every composer project has it's own composer.json )

This means cd into your project directory ...

```
cd /path/to/yourproject
```

... Before executing

```
/bin/composer.phar update ...
```

**Alternative:**

You can specify a working directory for composer with the **--working-dir** option.
This way you point composer to your project from any current working directory ( even if you project's path differs from where your cwd is ) . example usage:

```
composer --working-dir=/path/to/yourproject <command>
```

**Tip #1**

rename /bin/composer.phar to /bin/composer

```
mv /bin/composer.phar /bin/composer
chmod +x /bin/composer
```

Then you can simply ( assuming /bin is in your PATH ) ...

```
composer <command>
```

**Tip #2**

You can check where you currently are with pwd ( **p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory )

```
pwd
```