# RatChet PHP File structure and Installation issue

Tags: ratchet

I am a beginner in programming trying to implement Ratchet.

This is my current file structure

```
D:\Xampp
composer.phar
htdocs
      Ratchet
             composer.json
             bin
                Chat.php
             src
                Chat-Server.php
```

And I ran the command

```
php composer.phar install --dev
```

The following error message appears

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in D:\xampp
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the
http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

I tried using

```
 php composer.phar --working-dir=htdocs/Ratchet update
```

But it still doesn't work.
The tutorial on Ratchet is not very clear either, can someone guide me on what I should do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of duplicates this question:
[Updating the composer.phar on Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667932/updating-the-composer-phar-on-symfony2)

Though to answer it:

You need to run composer.phar in the directory in which your `composer.json` lies, so the correct execution path would be the Ratchet directory with this command:

`../../composer.phar install --dev`